# Slick producing bad SQL for MySQL (MyISAM)

Tags: mysql, scala, slick, myisam

I would like to analyze a legacy mysql database (myisam engine) using latest Slick (3.1.1).

Versions:

```
  scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.1"
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-codegen" % "3.1.1"
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.7.13"
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.38"
```

After using `slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator` to generate a Tables.scala from my database, I wrote a some trivial query code:

```
  val query = Users map { _.firstname }
  val action = query.result
  val future = db.run(action)
  future onSuccess {  
    case result => println("result: " + result)
  }
  future onFailure {
    case t => 
        println("Got an error: " + t.getMessage)
        println("SQL: " + action.statements.head)   
  }
```

The output looks like this:

```
Got an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"Users"' at line 1
SQL: select "FirstName" from "Users"
```

Those quotation marks look wrong to me. It should be `select FirstName from Users` instead, right?

What went wrong?

---

Rectification: It was a simple copy&paste fault of me. I forgot to replace that

```
object Tables extends { val profile = slick.driver.H2Driver } with demo.Tables
```

with

```
object Tables extends { val profile = slick.driver.MySQLDriver } with demo.Tables
```

Sorry!

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused. What is the -1 vote for? Please explain what is wrong with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quotes can be used to escape table and column names if MySQL is running in ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html for more information on SQL Modes.

Comment: It was my fault (bad copy&paste). I just used the wrong driver profile (slick.driver.H2Driver instead of slick.driver.MySQLDriver).